# Eclipse Mars + lombok + save actions

Tags: java, eclipse, lombok

I have a problem using Eclipse Mars (fresh new install, version: Mars Release 4.5.0, build id: 20150621-1200) with installed lombok v.1.16.4 on it.

I'm getting an error while saving, if "save actions" are activated and Java source code formatter is enabled (Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Save Actions -> "Format source code"). Here is an error message:

```
A save participant caused problems. The save participant 'Code Clean Up' caused an exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1. See the error log for details.
```

And a stacktrace in eclipse error log view:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.formatter.TokenManager.get(TokenManager.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.formatter.TokenManager.findIndex(TokenManager.java:161)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.formatter.TokenManager.lastIndexIn(TokenManager.java:198)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.formatter.LineBreaksPreparator.handleBracedCode(LineBreaksPreparator.java:544)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.formatter.LineBreaksPreparator.visit(LineBreaksPreparator.java:247)
at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.MethodDeclaration.accept0(MethodDeclaration.java:611)
at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2711)
at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.acceptChildren(ASTNode.java:2782)
at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.TypeDeclaration.accept0(TypeDeclaration.java:470)
at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2711)
at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.acceptChildren(ASTNode.java:2782)
at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.CompilationUnit.accept0(CompilationUnit.java:212)
at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2711)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.formatter.DefaultCodeFormatter.prepareLineBreaks(DefaultCodeFormatter.java:356)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.formatter.DefaultCodeFormatter.prepareFormattedCode(DefaultCodeFormatter.java:194)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.formatter.DefaultCodeFormatter.format(DefaultCodeFormatter.java:155)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.formatter.DefaultCodeFormatter.format(DefaultCodeFormatter.java:139)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.util.CodeFormatterUtil.reformat(CodeFormatterUtil.java:288)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.util.CodeFormatterUtil.reformat(CodeFormatterUtil.java:351)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.fix.CodeFormatFix.createCleanUp_aroundBody0(CodeFormatFix.java:69)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.fix.CodeFormatFix$AjcClosure1.run(CodeFormatFix.java:1)
at scala.tools.eclipse.contribution.weaving.jdt.ui.javaeditor.formatter.FormatterCleanUpRegistryAspect.ajc$around$scala_tools_eclipse_contribution_weaving_jdt_ui_javaeditor_formatter_FormatterCleanUpRegistryAspect$1$c12cf71dproceed(FormatterCleanUpRegistryAspect.aj:40)
at scala.tools.eclipse.contribution.weaving.jdt.ui.javaeditor.formatter.FormatterCleanUpRegistryAspect.ajc$around$scala_tools_eclipse_contribution_weaving_jdt_ui_javaeditor_formatter_FormatterCleanUpRegistryAspect$1$c12cf71d(FormatterCleanUpRegistryAspect.aj:46)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.fix.CodeFormatFix.createCleanUp(CodeFormatFix.java:54)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.fix.CodeFormatCleanUp.createFix(CodeFormatCleanUp.java:67)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.fix.CleanUpRefactoring.calculateChange_aroundBody0(CleanUpRefactoring.java:813)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.fix.CleanUpRefactoring$AjcClosure1.run(CleanUpRefactoring.java:1)
at scala.tools.eclipse.contribution.weaving.jdt.ui.javaeditor.formatter.FormatterCleanUpRegistryAspect.ajc$around$scala_tools_eclipse_contribution_weaving_jdt_ui_javaeditor_formatter_FormatterCleanUpRegistryAspect$2$805d5467proceed(FormatterCleanUpRegistryAspect.aj:51)
at scala.tools.eclipse.contribution.weaving.jdt.ui.javaeditor.formatter.FormatterCleanUpRegistryAspect.ajc$around$scala_tools_eclipse_contribution_weaving_jdt_ui_javaeditor_formatter_FormatterCleanUpRegistryAspect$2$805d5467(FormatterCleanUpRegistryAspect.aj:61)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.fix.CleanUpRefactoring.calculateChange(CleanUpRefactoring.java:799)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.fix.CleanUpPostSaveListener.saved(CleanUpPostSaveListener.java:396)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitDocumentProvider$5.run(CompilationUnitDocumentProvider.java:1598)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitDocumentProvider.notifyPostSaveListeners(CompilationUnitDocumentProvider.java:1593)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitDocumentProvider.commitWorkingCopy(CompilationUnitDocumentProvider.java:1380)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitDocumentProvider$4.execute(CompilationUnitDocumentProvider.java:1458)
at org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextFileDocumentProvider$DocumentProviderOperation.run(TextFileDocumentProvider.java:132)
at org.eclipse.ui.actions.WorkspaceModifyDelegatingOperation.execute(WorkspaceModifyDelegatingOperation.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.actions.WorkspaceModifyOperation$1.run(WorkspaceModifyOperation.java:108)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2241)
at org.eclipse.ui.actions.WorkspaceModifyOperation.run(WorkspaceModifyOperation.java:130)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.editors.text.WorkspaceOperationRunner.run(WorkspaceOperationRunner.java:75)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.editors.text.WorkspaceOperationRunner.run(WorkspaceOperationRunner.java:65)
at org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextFileDocumentProvider.executeOperation(TextFileDocumentProvider.java:456)
at org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextFileDocumentProvider.saveDocument(TextFileDocumentProvider.java:772)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.performSave(AbstractTextEditor.java:5076)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitEditor.performSave(CompilationUnitEditor.java:1244)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitEditor.doSave(CompilationUnitEditor.java:1298)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor$TextEditorSavable.doSave(AbstractTextEditor.java:7209)
at org.eclipse.ui.Saveable.doSave(Saveable.java:216)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.SaveableHelper.doSaveModel(SaveableHelper.java:357)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.SaveableHelper$3.run(SaveableHelper.java:201)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.SaveableHelper$5.run(SaveableHelper.java:285)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:463)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:371)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow$14.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:2156)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:2152)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.SaveableHelper.runProgressMonitorOperation(SaveableHelper.java:293)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.SaveableHelper.runProgressMonitorOperation(SaveableHelper.java:271)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.SaveableHelper.saveModels(SaveableHelper.java:213)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.SaveableHelper.savePart(SaveableHelper.java:148)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.saveSaveable(WorkbenchPage.java:3874)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.saveEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3888)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.SaveHandler.execute(SaveHandler.java:54)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:295)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:90)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:252)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:234)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:152)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:493)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:486)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:210)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.executeCommand(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:286)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.press(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:507)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.processKeyEvent(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:558)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.filterKeySequenceBindings(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:378)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.access$0(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:324)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher$KeyDownFilter.handleEvent(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:86)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.filterEvent(Display.java:1266)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1112)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1137)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1122)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1164)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1160)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.wmChar(Widget.java:1581)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_CHAR(Control.java:4781)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.WM_CHAR(Canvas.java:343)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4662)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:339)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5050)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(OS.java:2549)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3767)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:654)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:598)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
```

Has anyone a solution to get it working? Thanks in advance!

---

**Updated:** The similar problem if "Sort members" save action is enabled:

```
A save participant caused problems. The save participant 'Code Clean Up' caused an exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 5, Size: 5. See the error log for details.
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 5, Size: 5
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.formatter.TokenManager.get(TokenManager.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.formatter.TokenManager.findIndex(TokenManager.java:161)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.formatter.TokenManager.firstIndexIn(TokenManager.java:188)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.formatter.TokenManager.firstTokenIn(TokenManager.java:194)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.formatter.SpacePreparator.visit(SpacePreparator.java:196)
at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.MethodDeclaration.accept0(MethodDeclaration.java:611)
at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2711)
at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.acceptChildren(ASTNode.java:2782)
at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.TypeDeclaration.accept0(TypeDeclaration.java:470)
at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2711)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.formatter.DefaultCodeFormatter.prepareSpaces(DefaultCodeFormatter.java:350)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.formatter.DefaultCodeFormatter.prepareFormattedCode(DefaultCodeFormatter.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.formatter.DefaultCodeFormatter.format(DefaultCodeFormatter.java:155)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.formatter.DefaultCodeFormatter.format(DefaultCodeFormatter.java:139)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.dom.rewrite.ASTRewriteFormatter.formatString(ASTRewriteFormatter.java:246)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.dom.rewrite.ASTRewriteFormatter.formatNode(ASTRewriteFormatter.java:376)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.dom.rewrite.ASTRewriteFormatter.getFormattedResult(ASTRewriteFormatter.java:187)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.dom.rewrite.ASTRewriteAnalyzer.doTextInsert(ASTRewriteAnalyzer.java:1357)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.dom.rewrite.ASTRewriteAnalyzer$ListRewriter.rewriteList(ASTRewriteAnalyzer.java:771)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.dom.rewrite.ASTRewriteAnalyzer$ListRewriter.rewriteList(ASTRewriteAnalyzer.java:802)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.dom.rewrite.ASTRewriteAnalyzer.rewriteParagraphList(ASTRewriteAnalyzer.java:1175)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.dom.rewrite.ASTRewriteAnalyzer.visit(ASTRewriteAnalyzer.java:1811)
at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.TypeDeclaration.accept0(TypeDeclaration.java:453)
at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2711)
at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.rewrite.ASTRewrite.internalRewriteAST(ASTRewrite.java:302)
at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.rewrite.ASTRewrite.rewriteAST(ASTRewrite.java:233)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.SortElementsOperation.calculateEdit(SortElementsOperation.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jdt.core.util.CompilationUnitSorter.sort(CompilationUnitSorter.java:457)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.fix.SortMembersFix.createCleanUp(SortMembersFix.java:41)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.fix.SortMembersCleanUp.createFix(SortMembersCleanUp.java:66)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.fix.CleanUpRefactoring.calculateChange_aroundBody0(CleanUpRefactoring.java:809)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.fix.CleanUpRefactoring$AjcClosure1.run(CleanUpRefactoring.java:1)
at scala.tools.eclipse.contribution.weaving.jdt.ui.javaeditor.formatter.FormatterCleanUpRegistryAspect.ajc$around$scala_tools_eclipse_contribution_weaving_jdt_ui_javaeditor_formatter_FormatterCleanUpRegistryAspect$2$805d5467proceed(FormatterCleanUpRegistryAspect.aj:51)
at scala.tools.eclipse.contribution.weaving.jdt.ui.javaeditor.formatter.FormatterCleanUpRegistryAspect.ajc$around$scala_tools_eclipse_contribution_weaving_jdt_ui_javaeditor_formatter_FormatterCleanUpRegistryAspect$2$805d5467(FormatterCleanUpRegistryAspect.aj:61)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.fix.CleanUpRefactoring.calculateChange(CleanUpRefactoring.java:799)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.fix.CleanUpPostSaveListener.saved(CleanUpPostSaveListener.java:396)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitDocumentProvider$5.run(CompilationUnitDocumentProvider.java:1598)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitDocumentProvider.notifyPostSaveListeners(CompilationUnitDocumentProvider.java:1593)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitDocumentProvider.commitWorkingCopy(CompilationUnitDocumentProvider.java:1380)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitDocumentProvider$4.execute(CompilationUnitDocumentProvider.java:1458)
at org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextFileDocumentProvider$DocumentProviderOperation.run(TextFileDocumentProvider.java:132)
at org.eclipse.ui.actions.WorkspaceModifyDelegatingOperation.execute(WorkspaceModifyDelegatingOperation.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.actions.WorkspaceModifyOperation$1.run(WorkspaceModifyOperation.java:108)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2241)
at org.eclipse.ui.actions.WorkspaceModifyOperation.run(WorkspaceModifyOperation.java:130)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.editors.text.WorkspaceOperationRunner.run(WorkspaceOperationRunner.java:75)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.editors.text.WorkspaceOperationRunner.run(WorkspaceOperationRunner.java:65)
at org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextFileDocumentProvider.executeOperation(TextFileDocumentProvider.java:456)
at org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextFileDocumentProvider.saveDocument(TextFileDocumentProvider.java:772)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.performSave(AbstractTextEditor.java:5076)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitEditor.performSave(CompilationUnitEditor.java:1244)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitEditor.doSave(CompilationUnitEditor.java:1298)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor$TextEditorSavable.doSave(AbstractTextEditor.java:7209)
at org.eclipse.ui.Saveable.doSave(Saveable.java:216)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.SaveableHelper.doSaveModel(SaveableHelper.java:357)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.SaveableHelper$3.run(SaveableHelper.java:201)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.SaveableHelper$5.run(SaveableHelper.java:285)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:463)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:371)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow$14.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:2156)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:2152)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.SaveableHelper.runProgressMonitorOperation(SaveableHelper.java:293)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.SaveableHelper.runProgressMonitorOperation(SaveableHelper.java:271)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.SaveableHelper.saveModels(SaveableHelper.java:213)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.SaveableHelper.savePart(SaveableHelper.java:148)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.saveSaveable(WorkbenchPage.java:3874)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.saveEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3888)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.SaveHandler.execute(SaveHandler.java:54)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:295)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:90)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor81.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:252)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:234)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:152)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:493)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:486)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:210)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.executeCommand(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:286)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.press(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:507)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.processKeyEvent(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:558)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.filterKeySequenceBindings(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:378)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.access$0(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:324)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher$KeyDownFilter.handleEvent(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:86)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.filterEvent(Display.java:1266)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1112)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1137)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1122)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1164)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1160)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.wmChar(Widget.java:1581)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_CHAR(Control.java:4781)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.WM_CHAR(Canvas.java:343)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4662)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:339)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5050)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(OS.java:2549)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3767)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:654)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:598)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
```

Comment: It's apparently a bug in Eclipse. Why not report it into [Eclipse Bug Tracker](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi) instead? StackOverflow is not a bugtracker for every programming project.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am not sure whether it is eclipse related or lombok related bug. Just suppose, that eclipse+lombok combination may be frequently used and stackoverflow is the first candidate to ask for a problem solution after the comprehensive internet-wide searching. But I will try to track a possible bug report in Eclipse Bug Tracker, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eclipse Mars comes with a fresh new implementation of the code formatter, which is used by several actions that generate Java code.

Apparently, lombok breaks this formatter.

- Eclipse bugs, where reporters confirmed that the issue could be reproduced only with lombok in the loop: [Bug 472919](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=472919), [Bug 472858](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=472858)
- [Lombok bug](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/872).

Additionally, stack trace elements starting with `scala.tools.eclipse.contribution.weaving.jdt` indicate that the JDT byte code has been further modified by the Scala plugin. Just saying.

Comment: Installed snapshot version (1.16.5) of lombok, taken from [Lombok bug report](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/872) resolved this issue. Thanks for an investigation!